# How can I print the values of a *.json file in a *.html using Twig

Tags: arrays, json, twig

I would like to show the following values on screen with a "for ... in ..." loop, but I have trouble with the decoding of the *.json file and implementation.

```
// Example of *.json file
[{ "ano":       "2019",
   "nomeCurso": "ABI - CIÊNCIAS BIOLÓGICAS",
   "idCurso":   "01ABI",
   "grupo":     "PISM Grupo A",
   "campus":    "JUIZ DE FORA",
   "turno":     "DIURNO",
   "idGrupo":    75} }]
```

I have an index.php:

```
<?php

    // Putting the 'autoload' file of 'vendor' directory to use Twig
    require 'vendor/autoload.php';

    // Declaring directory 'views' (used to show using Twig)
    $loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem('views');

    // Loading 'views' directory
    $twig = new Twig_Environment($loader);

    // Create a filter to use in the code
    $md5Filter = new Twig_SimpleFilter('md5', function ($string) {
        return md5($string);
    });

    // Add filter
    $twig->addFilter($md5Filter);

    // Decode the *.json file
    $classificacoes = file_get_contents("PISM.json");
    $classificacao = json_decode($classificacoes, true);

    $twig->render('index.html.twig', array($classificacoes));

?>
```

...and an index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="description" content="Twig Table Template">
        <meta name="author" content="fabricioguidine">
        <meta name="keywords" content="twig table template">
        <title>Twig Table Template</title>
    </head>

    <body></body>

    <!-- for each value in "*.json" add a table with especified values -->

    {% for classicacao in classificacoes %}
        {{ classificacao.ano }}
        {{ classificacao.idCurso }}
        {{ classificacao.grupo }}
        {{ classificacao.campus }}
        {{ classificacao.turno }}
        {{ classificacao.idGrupo }}
    {% endfor %}

    </body>

    <footer></footer>

</html>
```

Note that I am a newbie in this framework and might be silly implementation errors.

*Could you help me with this, please?*

Comment: sidenote: You can chain functions in twig's filters and functions, e.g. `$twig->addFilter(new Twig_SimpleFilter('md5', 'md5'));`

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me you're transfering the wrong variable to your Twig template, and with a regular array instead of a hash array.

Instead of

```
$twig->render('index.html.twig', array($classificacoes));
```

try

```
$twig->render('index.html.twig', array('classificacoes' => $classificacao));
```